# Is an unlevel bed the reason I have trouble getting prints off a SpiderSheet?

Tags: print-quality, creality-ender-2

I've had a lot of trouble getting prints off of my build plate. So much so that I ripped off the SpiderSheet, cleaned the glass thoroughly, and applied a new one.

[image: Photo of the old SpiderSheet over the buildplate]

I ended up stopping the 1st print I did because it looked like the nozzle was digging into the bed. I had to go to 220 °C with this PLA because otherwise, it's all fluff. Is my issue perhaps an unlevel bed?

[image: Photo of a new SpiderSheet over the buildplate]

I run a Creality Ender-2 with an older firmware.

[image: Photo of the Ender-2 display showing the firmware as TH3D U1.R2.7]

Comment: What's your question? I suggest to change the title into an actual question.

Comment: If you have glass, why do you put a sheet on it? Glass is a perfect build surface. I have to agree with @BobOrtiz, what is your question? Do you want to ask why your prints stick so well, or why the nozzle digs in the new build surface. Please update your question so that it can be answered.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if the nozzle digs into the bed, then that means the nozzle is too close to the bed. That has nothing to do with the Spider Sheet or whatever other surface you are using. Two reasons come to mind:

1. Your bed is uneven/warped. While glass plates are normally pretty flat, you can bend them by clamping them down to a warped heated aluminum base.
2. Your X/Y axes (the guide rods) might be bent a little. If the bed or head is higher/lower in some positions than others, then the nozzle will touch the bed in some positions. Even if your bed were perfectly flat.

Possible solutions:

1. Re-level your bed (hopefully you have already done this before asking this question).
2. Add mesh bed leveling to your printer (don't know if your printer supports it though).

Comment: Another solution would be to increase the distance and flow rate on the first layer, and see if it's evenly squished. And if it's not, see if it is something op is willing to live with.